# how to iterate through each input files in a directory and using the values inside those files we could generate separate output files

Tags: linux, bash, shell, hadoop, ksh

I had some input files in a hdfs directory. I need to read each file for a certain code and **generate output files for each input file** in the hdfs path itself.  I tried to use a 'for loop' but it is taking the entire directory once and **generating **one** output file** for all the source files.
Here's the code I tried:-

```
#!/bin/ksh

hdfs_input='inputfilepath/'

for i in "${hdfs_input}"*

do

hdfs dfs -cp ${hdfs_input}*  ${hdfs_path}/new_dir/

#extracts generation code

done
```

After running the code,the files inside **hdfs_input** directory are being taken entirely like **hdfs_input/*** as input and generating output files into a single file. It is not iterating through each files and generating an output file for each.

I was a beginner to this shell script coding and don't have much idea to rectify it.
Thanks in advance and looking forward for help.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear what you want to do.
I think you want to.

1. Read files from an input path in hdfs
2. Read the contents of the hdfs files
3. Do something with the output of the files.

This code does that and hopefully will help you find a way to do what you want to do.  I humbly suggest that you learn spark as it's a better tool than bash for doing hdfs file manipulation.  (Although I must confess I've written a ton of scripts like this before so they have their place in your tool box of tricks.)

```
#!/bin/ksh

inputFilePath="/Some/Path/In/HDFS/"
hdfs_input=$(hdfs dfs -ls $inputFilePath) # get list of files from hdfs

for i in "${hdfs_input}"

do
  fileMarkers=$(hdfs dfs -cat $i) #read the contents of the file from hdfs

  hdfs dfs -cp ${fileMarkers}  ${hdfs_path}/new_dir/ #do something with the output

done
```

Comment: i  tried like this  to check the code-    input='hdfs://fullpath/'                                                                                            hdfs_input=$(hdfs dfs -ls $input)  for i in "${hdfs_input}";   do                                        echo $i  
fileMarkers=$( hdfs dfs -cat $i)    echo $fileMarkers                                                        done

Comment: but  the for loop is taking all the listed files from hdfs_input as single one because when i tried to print echo $i it prints all the file names together instead of taking 1 file at each   iteration.   As per the concept of for loop it should iterate only 1 file at a  time right?  and the Filemarkers parameter is also not getting the content of the files

Comment: Why don't you update the questions with your current code, and current output so I can help you?

Comment: I have resolved the issue.Thanks for your response.